# PHP incorrect date timezone than VPS Ubuntu system timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, ubuntu

I try to figure out an issue that seems to be impossible to understand for me.
I run PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 on an Ubuntu 12.04 system 
All works fine except the date that is 2 hours earlier in php `date('H:i:s');` function than the system time.
I've tried all of the config that I found in all documentation including:

- server system timezone `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` where is present the `date.timezone` and I set its value to `Europe/Bucharest`
- I run the system command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and followed the steps to set system timezone and reboot the machine (surprising the system timezone took effect but php still show a wrong date).
- I've even installed `ntp` and synced the system's timezone with `NTP Servers`
- I've put the php command `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');` on the top of php scripts
- I've even commented `date.timezone` in the `php.ini` in both directors `/etc/cli/` and `/etc/apache2`

The php time seems that remains untouched! 
Another weird think is that the MySQL command `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` shows the correct time.
What am I missing ?

More than this, the emails sent using `PHPMailer` library and a SMTP Google email account, are received 2 hours earlier than hour sent. I would like to fix this too.

Comment: What do the headers in the emails show?    Do they show the wrong time?

Comment: `Delivery-Date` is correct but `Date` is 2 hours erlier